# How to automatically pad a SQL Server column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My SQL Server table has a column defined as:

```
TicketNo varchar(5)
```

The rows in this table are inserted by some bulk load files from different sources.

Now, depending on who prepared the bulk load input files, sometimes `TicketNo` has leading 0s, sometimes not.

How can I enforce INSERTS to the table so that `TicketNo` will always be set with leading zeros, something like:

```
TicketNo = RIGHT('00000'+TicketNo, 5)
```

Comment: Did you try this SQL - `insert into table (ticketno,...) values (RIGHT('00000'+@TicketNo, 5),...);` ?

Comment: I have no control as to the actual INSERTs, they are done outside our group. At present I sometime run an UPDATE to set them correctly. What I was thinking it some kind of constraint to enforce the leading zeros automatically, if that is at all possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a char(5) column with a check constraint.

```
create table YourTable
(
  TicketNo char(5) check (patindex('%[^0-9]%', TicketNo) = 0)
)
```

Update:

Using [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34731/2103) by [Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith) it could look like this instead to make sure there are only 0-9 allowed.

```
create table YourTable
(
  TicketNo char(5) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS check (patindex('%[^0123456789]%', TicketNo) = 0) 
)
```

Comment: char(5) seems like a good idea, but the check constraint should probably take length into account as well, so something like `LEN(T) = 5 AND T NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'`

Comment: @JasonWhisman Not at all necessary with a char(5). It will always be 5.

Comment: This will cause inserts to fail if TicketNo is not 5 digits.  That's one interpretation of "enforce".  If the OP wants automatically update the value upon insert or update, rather than fail the operation, he might need an Insert,Update Trigger.

Comment: @GilM Yep, OP is asking for a constraint in a comment.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, and it's a reasonable interpretation of "constraint".  But, the inclusion of the expression RIGHT('00000'+TicketNo, 5) in the post makes me think he really wants SQL Server to apply the change, rather than require the client to do it.  I could be wrong (it happens a lot).

Comment: @GilM Only OP knows :). If that was the case I would personally turn the column into an integer with check < 100000 and a computed column that pads the zeros.

Comment: Also, and this is just a pet peeve of mine.. LEN(TicketNo) will not always be 5, even if TicketNo is a char(5) because LEN, for some idiotic reason, does not count trailing spaces. DATALENGTH(TicketNo) would always be 5...But, I'm not bitter. :-)

Comment: @GilM Yeah, I've fallen to the LEN() trap before. The `PATINDEX` does take care of the issue, at least; I was thinking that it might ignore the trailing spaces, but in testing found that it did not.

Comment: I can't use this constraint as it will fail the INSERT. @GilM you read my mind - I want SQL Server to apply the change rather than the client.

Comment: @dawntrader So, it seems like you either have to implement an insert/update trigger to do the update as per your expression in the post, or add a computed column if you can alter the schema and use a new column to hold the inserted, or final, value. Do you know how to do those things?

Answer (score 1):

How you enforce it is a tricky question.  My first through would be to create a stored procedure and force all inserts to take place through that.  Then you could use rs's solutions.

Other than that you can create an insert/update trigger that checks for leading zeros.